# How to draw samples from a categorical distribution in TensorFlow.js

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow.js, tfjs-node

#### Issue in short

In Python version of [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) there is a [tf.random.categorical()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/categorical) method that draws samples from a categorical distribution. But I can't find a similar method in [TensorFlow.js API](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/). **So, what is the proper way to draw samples from a categorical distribution in TensorFlow.js?**

#### Issue in details

In [Text generation with an RNN](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_generation) tutorial the [tf.random.categorical()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/categorical) method is being used in `generate_text()` function to decide what character should be passed next to the RNN input to generate a sequence.

```
predicted_id = tf.random.categorical(predictions, num_samples=1)[-1,0].numpy()
```

I'm experimenting with *TensorFlow.js* and trying trying to generate a "random" Shakespeare-like writing but in the browser. All parts of the tutorial seems to work well together except the step with using a `tf.random.categorical()` method.

I guess writing the alternative to `tf.random.categorical()` function manually should not be that hard, and also there are couple of 3rd-party JavaScript libraries that implement this functionality already, but it looks pretty logical to have it as a part of TensorFlow.js API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `tf.multinomial` instead.

I peeked at the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.1.0/tensorflow/python/ops/random_ops.py#L391-L416) and with `name` and `seed` parameters set to None, it is essentially the same as `tf.multinomial` with some random seeding going on, I guess.